# php handle array in array?

Tags: php, arrays

How can I handle an array in an array?

Like this:

```
Array
(
[page] => 1
[pages] => 391
[perpage] => 3
[total] => 1171
[photo] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 4539740346
                [owner] => 21229296@N03
                [secret] => 3b10921450
                [server] => 4040
                [farm] => 5
                [title] => ~ Berry One ~
                [ispublic] => 1
                [isfriend] => 0
                [isfamily] => 0
            )
```

edit:
how to echo all of it?
here is the array looks like:
http://www.qeeker.com/flickr

Comment: define "handle". What do you want to do?

Comment: PHP does support multidimensional arrays.

Comment: This question needs to be made much much clearer. It really isn't obvious what you're asking....

Answer (score 1):

You can get values from the array like this:

```
 echo $a['photo'][0]['ispublic']; //1
```

**UPDATE:**

In the comments you stated you want to display the photo stuff. In PHP, `foreach` can be used to iterate through an array:

```
foreach ($a['photo'] as $photo) {
    //$photo refers to the current photo on every iteration
    echo $photo['ispublic']; 
}
```

This snippet will echo the `ispublic` property of EVERY photo in the array. If you want to echo all the properties of all photos, you can use a nested `foreach` (one inside another).

Comment: yes, but is there any better way to do this? i need it display all the photo return, [0],[1] and so on.

Comment: @facebook Updated my answer. If you could clarify your question, I could help better. I'm running around in the dark trying to find out which part do you have a problem with.

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = array('page' => 1,
             'pages' => 391,
             'perpage' => 3,
             'total' => 1171,
             'photo' => array(array('id' => 4539740346,
                                    'owner' => '21229296@N03'
                                    'secret' => '3b10921450'
                                    'server' => 4040
                                    'farm' => 5
                                    'title' => '~ Berry One ~'
                                    'ispublic' => 1
                                    'isfriend' => 0
                                    'isfamily' => 0
                                    )
                               )
       );

var_dump($var);
```

Comment: @facebook-517003299 If you are using `print_r`, do you already have the array in place? In which case, what are you trying to do with it?